# Can the tag "resume" be changed to "résumé"?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There are a lot of items tagged [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume), however the proper spelling is "résumé". Is it possible to make the [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) tag be an alias of a "résumé" tag? I know that the accented E is supported in taxonomy (as well as other diacritics) because I can see those characters in https://french.stackexchange.com/

---

### Should be noted:

- While the `resume` spelling is in common usage, it is less formal and less common in more academic scholarship.
- This seems to be a question of "formal" as opposed to "informal", for while dictionaries do say that "resume" is a common spelling they unilaterally use résumé for the name of the entry. Historically, résumé is more correct.
- Diacritics do not break taxonomy at all.

Comment: +1 to the proposal

Comment: Apparently you seem to be on an editing spree, changing out "resume" for "résumé". I assume most of your edits are making it through but note that SE normally frowns on such insignificant edits. "Resume" is *not* incorrect, it's an accepted alternative spelling which makes such edits trivial. Changing American for British English is similarly not an acceptable edit.

Comment: I just edited your question with "résumé" as a tag and it... seems it was auto convered to "resume" :)

Comment: @enderland I know. :-(

Comment: Why bother? Nobody will be confused or inconvenienced by using the term "resume".

Comment: Nobody will be confused or inconvenienced by many things. It is a grammatical question, much like whether to capitalize "Facebook" as the logo has a lower case f.

Comment: You wrote 'unilaterally', but I think you meant 'universally', which is pretty much the opposite meaning.

Comment: @user52889 "Unilateral" can mean "one-sided". A "unilateral effort" can be undertaken by more than one party so long as each member of the party is taking the same effort.

Comment: In 35 years at work (UK)  I have never used the accented version of resume - I think most would think it pretentious think Niles in Frasier

Answer (score 10):

### **No**

As in: **we can, but we shouldn't**.

In modern English resume and résumé [are pretty much interchangeable](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/06/resume.html). Over time, loan words in American English seem to lose their diacritic marks as they lose their link to the original language. British English generally prefers CV over either.

**Since both are fine and the accented version is likely to wane in popularity in the coming years I don't see the point in changing it.**

---

## Update

The tag syntax "[ tag:tagname ]" for questions **does *not* work with accents**! This alone is sufficient reason not to proceed with the rename. I prefer [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) over [résumé](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) as  [tag:résumé] just doesn't work.

Comment: Also, keep in mind most people have keyboards with "e" characters - I do not have an "é" character on my keyboard and I suspect nearly all who type in English do not either..

Comment: @enderland That is all the more reason to keep it on as an alias. It would mean that someone would type in `resume` and get the expected `résumé`.

Comment: @cwallenpoole except most of your edits relate to changing the actual characters in question body/edits...

Comment: Wikipedia's take: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9

Comment: @enderland Not the question at hand :-P

Comment: Also, should be noted, that while the article you cite does mention that "resume" is common, Wikipedia, freedictionary.com, as well as *BOTH* dictionaries that post cites use the spelling "résumé" for the *name* of the entry. This implies that résumé is the more expected spelling.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Conversely, [Alison Green] and a few other workplace/management bloggers that I've read exclusively use "resume". The [tag:résumé]  tag also looks fairly odd in my opinion.

Comment: The "resume" tag looks more odd in my opinion. It looks like it's defaulting the ASCII instead of unicode.

Comment: And a cursory look at the `Harvard Business Review` suggests that résumé is more common among its authors.

Comment: As a general rule – it is hard to go wrong erring on the side of formal English.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Updated my post: diacritic marks break tag syntax in questions and answers. Enough of a reason to go for a firm no on this in my opinion.

Comment: @Lilienthal As I mentioned, I checked french.stackexchange.com before asking. Otherwise I would have reported this as a bug. `[tag:compléments]` works there.

Comment: @Lilienthal The problem is that `résumé` is not a tag. The highlighting syntax won't work because the tag doesn't exist. If you were to create a tag `flambé` you could use `[tag:flambé]`. Diacritics have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @cwallenpoole just FYI, as a moderator (or user with lots of rep) I can create tags, and tried on your question here, but it seems on Workplace this is not supported currently.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Tested on the French site: creating fake tags in the editor correctly displays tag syntax but this is not the case here. Seems like a site limitation as enderland suggests.

Comment: @Lilienthal @enderland That seems like a bug. I am able to create tags in both Christianity and SO, in SO it supports `é`, Christianity does not. french does. This one does not.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Either that or [a site setting according to @enderland](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25912844#25912844).

Comment: Forwarded the "why" to here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270362/why-are-diacritics-not-supported-in-tags-consistently

Answer (score 9):

My thoughts:

As a non-French speaker, I do not have an easy way to make the `é` character on my Windows keyboard I use at work (at home I have a mac and mac users can fairly easily if they are savvy, but most probably don't realize this?). I will still type "resume" 100% of the time, both for the tag and for text of questions/etc.

I don't really think this matters, either since as you say the documentation suggests either spelling is appropriate.

I also don't really want to start a edit war over British vs American English spelling. My recommendation would be to just let users spell it however they want. If context here was less clear, and it wasn't clear whether users wanted to use it as a verb or the noun, then maybe it would matter more.

Comment: The reason I thought we could make this the default is because it would mean that an American with Windows would be able to type `resume` and the accented word would appear. We have something very similar right now – someone who puts the accents in the words will find that the default *removes* them. That seems to be a SE setting? bug? though.

Comment: @cwallenpoole But  a person may not want to use the only meaning of the word, it's like the history of the word clbuttic. What if you wanted to actually use the word resume, and not résumé? We'd then see lots of complaining posts about it.

Answer (score -1):

As a non-American, I call it a CV. I am not familiar with the word *résumé* in this context. I can certainly understand the word, but I’m not *familiar* with it, which means that it’s not the first thing that comes to mind when I see *resume*. I will read that as written, as a word which Collins defines as “to begin again or go on with (something adjourned or interrupted)”. Only when that definition makes no sense do I mentally rewrite it in my head and pick the other definition. This means that every single time I see the word, there’s a brief mental hiccough: my train of thought goes down the wrong path and needs to be recalled. Spelling the word correctly, as *résumé*, would definitely help that.

The tag should definitely be given the accents, with the non-accented version synonomized. Due to improvements in the tag engine, this is now possible.

Comment: (And it’s hardly difficult to type, AltGr+e is not a difficult key combination.)

Comment: Considering standard American keyboards don't have an AltGr key, yes, it is difficult. There are Alt+xxxx combinations for non-standard characters, but since American English does not typically use accented characters, I would not expect anyone to know what they are.